# Count the rows with same ID in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to count the rows with the same id

```
|curs_code|cursistnr|Mark|Payed|
    C#        20       6    50
    PHP       25       8    100
    C#        8        7    100
```

the output needs to be

C#, 2times

I've tried

```
$sql = "SELECT count(curs_code) as 'count_of_curs' FROM cursus where curs_code='$id'";
$query = $magazijn->query($sql);
return $query->fetchAll());
```

but gives me this output:

```
C#
 array (size=1)
  0 => 
   array (size=2)
    'count_of_curs' => string '1' (length=1)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)

PHP
 array (size=1)
  0 => 
   array (size=2)
    'count_of_curs' => string '1' (length=1)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
```

your thought about this?

Comment: I think you need to GROUP the results, google it :)

Comment: How do you mean group?

Comment: It looks like the problem you are reporting is that you expect a count of 2 to be returned, but the count is returning 1. I think what this means is that the two occurrences of **`C#`** appear to be the same to you, but they are actually *different* values, likely due to "hidden" whitespace characters in one of the values.  As a test, try a query like **`SELECT curs_code, HEX(curs_code), CHAR_LENGTH(curs_code) FROM cursus WHERE curs_code LIKE '%C#%'`**.

Comment: For your query, the group by is not required, you count all rows given by the where clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELECT curs_code, count(*) as 'count_of_curs' FROM cursus where curs_code='$id' group by curs_code

Remove the where if you want the entire list.

Comment: You need to echo it with $countDown[0]['count_of_curs'] though

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the question you are asking is **"Why is the expression `COUNT(curs_code)` returning a value of 1 when I expect a value of 2?"**

I think what this means is that the *two* occurrences of **`C#`** that appear to be the same to you are actually *different* values. This is likely due to "hidden" whitespace characters in one of the values.

To return all values of `curs_code` that contain the string **`C#`**, and to "see" what is actually stored, run a query like this:

```
SELECT curs_code
     , HEX(curs_code)
     , CHAR_LENGTH(curs_code)
  FROM cursus
 WHERE curs_code LIKE '%C#%'
```

As a demonstration:

```
  SELECT cc
       , HEX(cc)
       , CHAR_LENGTH(cc)
    FROM ( SELECT 'C#' AS cc
           UNION ALL SELECT 'C#\t'
           UNION ALL SELECT 'C#\0'
         ) c  
   WHERE cc LIKE '%C#%'


  cc   HEX(cc)  CHAR_LENGTH(cc)  
  ---  -------  ---------------
  C#   4323                   2
  C#   432309                 3
  C#   432300                 3
```

---

If you just want to find "duplicate" values of curs_code:

```
  SELECT c.curs_code
       , COUNT(1) AS count_of_curs_code
    FROM cursus
   GROUP BY c.curs_code
  HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
   ORDER BY c.curs_code
```